# how to check the shipping number in bulk?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently received a significant increase in orders and I'm having a lot of trouble checking the tracking number manually. How do I bulk check tracking numbers on nodejs? for the website, you can use this https://m.trackingmore.com/global-tracking.html?number=S00000188733460

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically interact with a service, the first thing you should do is check if they have a public API.

You're in luck in this case as Tracking More does have one. Explore their documentation to find out how to do what you want. If you're having trouble implementing it, then you may come back to post a new question.

https://www.trackingmore.com/api-index.html

Happy Coding!